# How do I perform this integration?

Tags: integration, normal-distribution

I tried doing it by parts, but I keep getting stuck.

> Show that $\int t\phi(t)dt=-\phi(t)+c$,
>
> where $c$ is a constant
>
> $\:\qquad\phi$ is the pdf of a standard normal variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$te^{-t^{2}/2}$ is the derivative of $-e^{-t^{2}/2}$. Hence its integral is $-e^{-t^{2}/2}+C$.